# Replace cell contents with multiple cells

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any way to replace a cell with multiple cells and have them relate to other multiple cell substitutions?  The following example shows the substitution of the first line of worksheet A.

Worksheet A:

[image: pic2]

With a substitution logic in Worksheet B where the items in column A should be replaced with the corresponding item in column B. Everywhere zd is used, it should become a_zd, b_zd, and y_zd.  Everywhere fs is used, it should become c_fs, y_fs, and z_fs. Example: A1=zd and B1=a_zd; A2=zd and B2=b_zd; A3=zd and B3=y_zd; A4=fs and B4=c_fs; A5=fs and B5=y_fs; A6=fs and B6=z_fs:

[image: pic2]

The substitution of the first line in Worksheet A will have a result of Worksheet C. Example: A1=a_zd and B1=c_fs; A2=a_zd and B2=y_fs; A3=a_zd and B3=z_fs;  A4=b_zd and B4=c_fs; A5=b_zd and B5=y_fs; A6=b_zd and B6=z_fs;  A7=y_zd and B7=c_fs; A8=y_zd and B8=y_fs; A9=y_zd and B9=z_fs;:

[image: pic2]

Comment: The data in your example doesn't really make sense to me. what happened to "ad" and "ds"? your text describes the image and not the transformation that has occurred. Write instructions detailing the steps you take to get from start to finish for each row. Use that to start writing your code.

Comment: ...this is not a clear question and that is probably why it has been down-voted

Comment: Sorry about that.  The example only showed the substitution of the first line in worksheet 1:  zd and fs.  The substitution dictates that everywhere zd is used should instead show a_zd, b_zd, or y_zd, and everywhere fs is used should instead show c_fs, y_fs, and z_fs.  The result of the substitution is the nine pairings listed in worksheet 3 (the bottom example).

Comment: So worksheet A is input 1, and input 2 in columns A and B?  Then the second screen shot shows a one to many relationship between the input values and the output values?  Then the third shows all the combinations resulting from the first input row?  I don't suppose you're using an older version of Excel that came with Microsoft Query?  This is a problem much more simply solved with SQL than with Excel formulas.

Comment: You are exactly right Denise.  I have Excel 2010 and I'm not familiar with Microsoft Query.

Comment: Please mark the answer that solved your question as "accepted" to mark this question "solved". Don't add pseudo-tags like "solved" to the title of your questions, that isn't how Stack Overflow works.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Sub CombineData()
    Dim myInput As Range
    Dim myOutput As Range
    Dim inputTwoValues As Collection
    Dim output1 As Collection
    Dim output2 As Collection
    Dim anOutput1 As Variant
    Dim anOutput2 As Variant

    Set myInput = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
    Set myOutput = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1")

    Do
        Set output1 = GetRelatedValues(myInput.Value)
        Set output2 = GetRelatedValues(myInput.Offset(0, 1).Value)
        For Each anOutput1 In output1
            For Each anOutput2 In output2
                myOutput.Formula = anOutput1
                myOutput.Offset(0, 1).Formula = anOutput2
                Set myOutput = myOutput.Offset(1, 0)
            Next
        Next
        Set myInput = myInput.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop While myInput.Value <> ""
End Sub


Function GetRelatedValues(myInput As Variant) As Collection
    Dim returnVal As New Collection
    Dim myRelationship As Range
    Set myRelationship = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")

    While myRelationship.Value <> ""
        If myRelationship.Value = myInput Then
            returnVal.Add (myRelationship.Offset(0, 1).Value)
        End If
        Set myRelationship = myRelationship.Offset(1, 0)
    Wend
    Set GetRelatedValues = returnVal
End Function
```

Comment: For maintenance reasons, you may want to rename the input/output variables to something that makes sense in your business logic.